# Meaning of + and - in an electronic component's part number

Tags: components

I have search in the internet and I could not really get an answer for this question. "What does \$\mathbf{+}\$ and \$\mathbf{-}\$ mean in an electronic component's part number?"

Comment: That depends on the manufacturer.  - is often just a hyphen, separating parts of it out.  + sometimes denotes RoHS compliant.

Comment: @Majenko thanks for the answer.. it's now clearer.. thanks for that.. so basically part numbers with and without + sign would be the same but the one with the + is compliant to RoHS? right?

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, it means nothing.

Comment: I've seen a few Maxim parts use these symbols to denote lead-free

Comment: yeah, thats what i first thought @Andyaka. but Majenko is making sense too.. i keep on searching the net about this but i can't seem to find a really good answer. kudos to you guys for the sensible answers..

Comment: Can you give some examples?  I don't think I've seen any part numbers with +/- signs in them (hyphens frequently in IC part number, separating speed grade from the basic number, but not minus signs).  In any case, you should consult the part's datasheet to find how the part number is formed.